# how to use jenkins dsl-plugin to pull the DB for 500 applications

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

We have 500 applications running in prod and we have all the applications info in DB.

We need to use jenkins job and tasks. In each job we will have 3 tasks to perform, i.e.

1. read the application info from db into log
2. stop the application
3. verify the logs if application is stopped properly.

I want these 3 tasks to be performed for every application.

- Is there any easy way to do it instead of having 500 jobs for 500 applications and all the applications are independent?
- Any way to run them parallel?

Our jenkins is not yet installed too, it would be used only for this automation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can use (almost) arbitrary Groovy code. Just figure out, how to read from your database of choice - or build e.g. a REST service to decouple it more cleanly and consume this from groovy.

Comment: Further: please be more specific, when you have a particular problem. You are very broad. Finally, please keep an eye on your spelling and formatting. Your post is awkward to read.